# xslt: removing node based on its child element value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need your help on fixing my xslt.

My requirement is to remove specific child node based on its decedents(grandchild) value.

in the  below example, i need to write an xslt which gives me xml containing 
 whose decedent "SID" value not equal to "1113181"

## Input XML:

```
<CDM CDMVersion="1.3" FType="Transactional" FOID="85b40b86-e6f1-4813-a5f4-0b98c90bd72d" CreationDateTime="2016-08-19T19:04:25" xmlns="http://www.example.com/ns/CDM/v1.3" xmlns:xyz="http://www.example.com/ns/CDM/MData">
   <TestData EduOID="LX4211-204" MDataVersionOID="34" xyz:AuditSubCategoryName="Verify">
      <SubData SubKey="5117f771-790f-4cde-b261-1a2db0dcd04b" xyz:SubKeyType="SubUUID" xyz:SubName="204-0114-002">
         <SRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
         <SubEventData EduEventOID="EOT" EduEventRepeatKey="EOT[1]" xyz:InstanceId="76194">
            <FmData FmOID="VS2" FmRepeatKey="1" xyz:DataPageId="388465">
               <IGroupData IGroupOID="VS2" xyz:RecordId="1044557">
                  <IData ItemOID="VS2.VSORRES4_2" TransactionType="Upsert" xyz:Verify="Yes">
                     <Record>
                        <TesterRef TesterOID="bballardamad1"/>
                        <LocRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
                        <DateTimeStamp>2016-08-16T17:07:15</DateTimeStamp>
                        <ReasonForChange/>
                        <SID>1113181</SID>
                     </Record>
                  </IData>
               </IGroupData>
            </FmData>
         </SubEventData>
      </SubData>
   </TestData>
   <TestData EduOID="LX4211-204" MDataVersionOID="34" xyz:AuditSubCategoryName="QueryClose">
      <SubData SubKey="5117f771-790f-4cde-b261-1a2db0dcd04b" xyz:SubKeyType="SubUUID" xyz:SubName="204-0114-002">
         <SRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
         <SubEventData EduEventOID="EOT" EduEventRepeatKey="EOT[1]" xyz:InstanceId="76194">
            <FmData FmOID="VS2" FmRepeatKey="1" xyz:DataPageId="388465">
               <IGroupData IGroupOID="VS2" xyz:RecordId="1044557">
                  <IData ItemOID="VS2.VSORRES4_2" TransactionType="Upsert">
                     <Record>
                        <TesterRef TesterOID="bballardamad1"/>
                        <LocRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
                        <DateTimeStamp>2016-08-16T17:07:15</DateTimeStamp>
                        <ReasonForChange/>
                        <SID>1113182</SID>
                     </Record>
                     <xyz:Query QueryRepeatKey="552326" Status="Closed" Recipient="Site from CRA"/>
                  </IData>
               </IGroupData>
            </FmData>
         </SubEventData>
      </SubData>
   </TestData>
   <TestData EduOID="LX4211-204" MDataVersionOID="34" xyz:AuditSubCategoryName="Verify">
      <SubData SubKey="5117f771-790f-4cde-b261-1a2db0dcd04b" xyz:SubKeyType="SubUUID" xyz:SubName="204-0114-002">
         <SRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
         <SubEventData EduEventOID="WK1_POST" EduEventRepeatKey="WK1_POST[1]" xyz:InstanceId="119171">
            <FmData FmOID="VS2" FmRepeatKey="1" xyz:DataPageId="670872">
               <IGroupData IGroupOID="VS2" xyz:RecordId="1934354">
                  <IData ItemOID="VS2.VSORRES12" TransactionType="Upsert" xyz:Verify="Yes">
                     <Record>
                        <TesterRef TesterOID="bballardamad1"/>
                        <LocRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
                        <DateTimeStamp>2016-08-16T17:09:10</DateTimeStamp>
                        <ReasonForChange/>
                        <SID>1114610</SID>
                     </Record>
                  </IData>
               </IGroupData>
            </FmData>
         </SubEventData>
      </SubData>
   </TestData>
</CDM>
```

================================================================================

My XSLT:

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<!--<xsl:template match="//SID[text()!=1113181]"/>-->
 <xsl:template match="/CDM/TestData/SubData/SubEventData/FmData/IGroupData/IData/Record/SID[text()!=68943181]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Expected Output:

#

```
<CDM CDMVersion="1.3" FType="Transactional" FOID="85b40b86-e6f1-4813-a5f4-0b98c90bd72d" CreationDateTime="2016-08-19T19:04:25" xmlns="http://www.example.com/ns/CDM/v1.3" xmlns:xyz="http://www.example.com/ns/CDM/MData">
   <TestData EduOID="LX4211-204" MDataVersionOID="34" xyz:AuditSubCategoryName="QueryClose">
      <SubData SubKey="5117f771-790f-4cde-b261-1a2db0dcd04b" xyz:SubKeyType="SubUUID" xyz:SubName="204-0114-002">
         <SRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
         <SubEventData EduEventOID="EOT" EduEventRepeatKey="EOT[1]" xyz:InstanceId="76194">
            <FmData FmOID="VS2" FmRepeatKey="1" xyz:DataPageId="388465">
               <IGroupData IGroupOID="VS2" xyz:RecordId="1044557">
                  <IData ItemOID="VS2.VSORRES4_2" TransactionType="Upsert">
                     <Record>
                        <TesterRef TesterOID="bballardamad1"/>
                        <LocRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
                        <DateTimeStamp>2016-08-16T17:07:15</DateTimeStamp>
                        <ReasonForChange/>
                        <SID>1113182</SID>
                     </Record>
                     <xyz:Query QueryRepeatKey="552326" Status="Closed" Recipient="Site from CRA"/>
                  </IData>
               </IGroupData>
            </FmData>
         </SubEventData>
      </SubData>
   </TestData>
   <TestData EduOID="LX4211-204" MDataVersionOID="34" xyz:AuditSubCategoryName="Verify">
      <SubData SubKey="5117f771-790f-4cde-b261-1a2db0dcd04b" xyz:SubKeyType="SubUUID" xyz:SubName="204-0114-002">
         <SRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
         <SubEventData EduEventOID="WK1_POST" EduEventRepeatKey="WK1_POST[1]" xyz:InstanceId="119171">
            <FmData FmOID="VS2" FmRepeatKey="1" xyz:DataPageId="670872">
               <IGroupData IGroupOID="VS2" xyz:RecordId="1934354">
                  <IData ItemOID="VS2.VSORRES12" TransactionType="Upsert" xyz:Verify="Yes">
                     <Record>
                        <TesterRef TesterOID="bballardamad1"/>
                        <LocRef LocOID="LX4211204_0114"/>
                        <DateTimeStamp>2016-08-16T17:09:10</DateTimeStamp>
                        <ReasonForChange/>
                        <SID>1114610</SID>
                     </Record>
                  </IData>
               </IGroupData>
            </FmData>
         </SubEventData>
      </SubData>
   </TestData>
</CDM>
```

#

Answer (score 2):

There are four reasons why your attempt doesn't work:

1. If you want a template to remove `TestData`, make it match `TestData` - not its descendant;
2. The elements of your input XML are in a *namespace*; you need to declare a prefix and use it when matching/selecting them;
3. If you want to **keep** `<TestData>` whose descendant `SID` value **does not** equal `1113181`, then make your **removing** template match `TestData` whose descendant `SID` value **does** equal `1113181`;
4. `68943181` is not `1113181`.

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cdm="http://www.example.com/ns/CDM/v1.3">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cdm:TestData[cdm:SubData/cdm:SubEventData/cdm:FmData/cdm:IGroupData/cdm:IData/cdm:Record/cdm:SID=1113181]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and quick response michael...        i have taken care of point1,3 and 4. Unfortunately , i dont have privilege to add namespace to the input xml, as it is generated by other system. I tried                                                                                       <xsl:template match="TestData[SubData/SubEventData/FmData/IGroupData/IData/Record/SID=1113181]"/>                                                                        but could see expected result. Could you please shed some more light on this???

Comment: You are not supposed to "*add namespace to the input xml*". Does the suggested XSLT not work for you?

Comment: appreciate your help on this. Yes... it did work infact !!!, thank  you michael ...